# Data Flow Task Hangs forever

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, oledb, etl

I am new to SSIS, I have developed a simple solution that takes data from a FLAT FILE SOURCE, does some data conversions and Inserts this data into a database table using OLEDB Destination Task.
My problem is it works fine on my test database, When I change the database connection, it gets stuck forever in the the Control Flow task and never gets into data flow task(The Data Flow Task continues to remain yellow instead of turning Green).

After around 30 minutes, it goes forward and gives me an error at OLEDB destination block saying "Out Of Memory" as shown below.

> [OLE DB Destination [589]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x8007000E.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft Cursor Engine"  Hresult: 0x8007000E  Description: "Out of memory.".
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (589) failed with error code 0xC0202009 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (602). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Please Help me with this.

Comment: I recommend actually pasting the errors into the question. This enables your question to appear in search results and thus gives you a better chance of getting an answer

Comment: How many rows are you trying to import?

Comment: rows are not more than 10 @BIDeveloper

Comment: You also need to drill into the data flow task and see if it's stuck on the source or the target (or any transformations in between)

Comment: First it gets stuck in the Data flow task block in control flow, and after 30 minutes it gives me an error in the OLEDB destination task, The previous blocks turn green when I get an error in OLEDB destination block.

Comment: You need to drill _into_ the data flow task block. In there will be a source and a destination and maybe some transformations. Does the source go yellow? Does the destination go yellow? How many rows are you copying and do you have any particularly large columns? Are the versions of the target databases the same?

Comment: Does your dataflow look something like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XHKr0.png (which is linked to from a very similar question, also without an answer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654790/issue-when-transfering-data-to-oracle-from-sql-using-ssis

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Nick.McDermaid . Nothing goes green, its just the data flow task in the Control Flow that turns yellow, no block in the data flow task even turns yellow. yeah after 30 minutes I get an error in the OLEDB Destination after the preceeding blocks turn green. There are hardly 10 rows and yes Versions are same for target DB.

Comment: If you're saying that _inside_ the data flow, neither the source nor destination changes colour at all, then that tells us something..... but I'm not sure what! It basically says it can't even start sucking data out of the source database, which makes no sense considering you are only changing the target database. What happens if you export to a flat file instead?